# Использую вход с помощью апи фейсбука на фрагменте

Tags: android

Использую вход с помощью апи фейсбука на фрагменте, и получается после нажатия кнопки войти с помощью фейсбук, onActivityResult - отрабатывает в активности а не в фрагменте где у меня весь код, как мне можно выйти с данной ситуации? Сам я не вызываю startactivityforresult.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17081653/3212712) надо прочитать [доку](https://github.com/TechIsFun/android-facebook-login-example/tree/master/src/com/example/facebook) и найти там метод, устанавливающий фрагмент для кнопки логина так:

```
facebookLoginButton.setFragment(this);
```

Comment: частично взял код с этого примера на гите и заработало, спасибо.